# Switching from Nexus Mod Manager to Mod Organiser?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, nexus-mod-manager

Hi I have 76 mods installed nmm and now want to switch to MO so I can have multiple profiles (starting a new playthrough with different mods). How can I transfer all the mods across to MO from NMM because I want to remove NMM completely

Thanks

Comment: Since I only use Nexus, I'm going to guess that you MIGHT be able to move the files from <drive letter>\Games\Skyrim\mods (The nexus mod folder), into <drive letter>\Mod Organizer\mods.